# I cannot locate the declaration of a site-wide variable

Tags: php, variables, declaration

I am not an experienced .php programmer but know enough to understand the code. A 3rd party company built a site for me where they are using a variable called domain and echoing that in the URL paths.

```
<?php echo domain;?>css/style.css
```

The variable is not declared on the page with $domain
I cannot find where this variable is declared anywhere in the .php pages. Where else should I be looking for this?

Comment: I would try grepping your entire project and going through each file that returns results. You might have some work on your hands though, that name is pretty generic and may be widely used in other places.

Comment: The easiest way will probably be to use `Find in all files` in your editor

Comment: Is it really `echo domain` and not `echo $domain`?

Comment: a config file ?, search for define('domain' ? search for the domain name as echoed ?, is that defined from a variable in a database?

Comment: If it really is just `domain` (without the `$`) it is done using `define("domain", [...])`

Comment: Yes the dollar sign ($) is not used for any instances.

Comment: @akirk is right, you are looking for a constant declaration, not a variable declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this "variable" have not a `$` before name, it is a constant.

Constants are defined in PHP using

`define("constant_name", "constant_value");`

Then you should find in your files for

`define("domain"` or just for `define(`

And find the line that set the domain.

Comment: I found it. It was set using a variable populated by a database query. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

1) `grepping` the `variable name` via `terminal` or any other `cli` throughout your project

2) search in all the `includes` in that file

3) search through all `config` and `extended` files

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  define("domain","somethingsomethingblabla");
?>
```

You add this to one of the files where `echo domain;` exists, but **before any includes**, at the very top of the file.

So when you open that file, it will define the `domain` constant, and when that same constant is defined in one of the included files, php will throw notice saying:

`PHP Notice: Constant domain already defined in /path/to/file.php on line XX`

And voila, there you go, there is a call to define `domain` constant.